# i hava problem in mongodb query its show TypeError: Product.group is not a function

Tags: database, mongodb

Here is the query below:

```
db.products.group({ 
            "key": { 
                "partId": true 
            }, 
            "initial": {},
            "reduce": function(obj, prev) { 
                prev._id = isNaN(prev._id) ? obj._id : Math.max(prev._id, obj._id);
            }
        });
```

When I compiler my code it show TypeError:

```
Product.group is not a function.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check your version.

```
DEPRECATED SINCE VERSION 3.4
```

Mongodb 3.4 deprecates the `db.collection.group()` method. Use `db.collection.aggregate()` with the `$group` stage or `db.collection.mapReduce()` instead.

[For reference](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.group/)

Comment: can you convert this group query into aggregate? In My table there are various duplicate partId. i want to get unieqe part id behalf of MONGO ID.

Comment: Can you provide an ex: of a document and expected result.